# how do I choose number of threads for Executor

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

When creating a thread pool with `Executor` as in the code below how does one choose an appropriate value for `nThreads`? Can I ask android for the number of cores that the device has and then use that information to calculate this number? What should that number be in that case?

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
```

Answer (score 5):

> Can I ask android for the number of cores that the device has and then use that information to calculate this number?

Yes. You can use `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` to do this.